# Azure Service Bus - ARM Template (Update existing Topic parameters)

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azureservicebus, azure-resource-manager, azure-servicebus-topics

I need help with the Azure service bus service. I need to create a new topic in an existing service bus service by using Visual Studio, is there any way to achieve this. Because when I try to do this, I’m getting the following error:

- Template deployment returned the following errors:
  15:28:14 - 15:28:13 - Resource Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces “#######” failed with message '{
  15:28:14 -   "error": {
  15:28:14 -     "message": "Namespace update failed with conflict in backend. CorrelationId: 3c155444-2c1e-525d-943f-8b25d0a1da7e",
  15:28:14 -     "code": "Conflict"
  15:28:14 -   }

Any help would be very helpful to me.

Comment: that isn't a particularly helpful error text :) you mind sharing the template and the inputs you are passing to the template?

Comment: Please ensure that there’s no queue or topic by the same name (one you’re trying to create) in the account.

Comment: I use the following template :

https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-servicebus-create-topic-and-subscription


But, I understand that with this template we create Topics, in my case I want to update parameters in an existing topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Microsoft.Resources/deployments` template allows you to [update an existing resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/building-blocks/extending-templates/update-resource).

Modifiying the quickstart template to allow updates looks something like this (I did remove the subscription deployment to make it a bit shorter). Keep in mind that some parameters like partitioning cannot be modified- you must delete the resource and redeploy to change them.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "service_BusNamespace_Name": {
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Name of the Service Bus namespace"
      }
    },
    "serviceBusTopicName": {
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Name of the Topic"
      }
    },
    "serviceBusSubscriptionName": {
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Name of the Subscription"
      }
    },
    "location": {
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Location for all resources."
      }
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "defaultSASKey_Name": "RootManageSharedAccessKey",
    "authRuleResource_Id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/authorizationRules', parameters('service_BusNamespace_Name'), variables('defaultSASKey_Name'))]",
    "sbVersion": "2017-04-01"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "apiVersion": "2015-01-01",
      "name": "updateTopic",
      "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "parameters": {},
        "template": {
          "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
          "parameters": {},
          "variables": {},
          "resources": [
            {
              "apiVersion": "2017-04-01",
              "name": "[parameters('service_BusNamespace_Name')]",
              "type": "Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces",
              "location": "[parameters('location')]",
              "sku": {
                "name": "Standard"
              },
              "resources": [
                {
                  "apiVersion": "2017-04-01",
                  "name": "[parameters('serviceBusTopicName')]",
                  "type": "Topics",
                  "dependsOn": [
                    "[concat('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/', parameters('service_BusNamespace_Name'))]"
                  ],
                  "properties": {
                    "defaultMessageTimeToLive": "P10675199DT2H48M5.4775807S",
                    "maxSizeInMegabytes": "1024",
                    "requiresDuplicateDetection": "false",
                    "duplicateDetectionHistoryTimeWindow": "PT10M",
                    "enableBatchedOperations": "false",
                    "supportOrdering": "false",
                    "autoDeleteOnIdle": "P10675199DT2H48M5.4775807S",
                    "enablePartitioning": "false",
                    "enableExpress": "false"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {
    "NamespaceConnectionString": {
      "type": "String",
      "value": "[listkeys(variables('authRuleResource_Id'), variables('sbVersion')).primaryConnectionString]"
    },
    "SharedAccessPolicyPrimaryKey": {
      "type": "String",
      "value": "[listkeys(variables('authRuleResource_Id'), variables('sbVersion')).primaryKey]"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually you get "conflict in backend" errors when you request an operation that isn't allowed in the resource's current state.

For example, once you upgrade Service Buses to Standard, deployments will fail if it tries to downgrade to Basic.

Effectively, the only solution for those cases is re-provision the resource from scratch.